# Injecting a query within a query that has an order by or group by function

Tags: sql-injection, mysql, sqlmap

```
Select * from Shop where Item = $item order by ProductNum desc
```

I found this vulnerability within a website. To test if there's any vulnerabilities I inserted a single quotation after

```
itemshop_secure.php?section=
```

And I stumbled upon this error message

```
Error Query [SELECT * FROM Shop Where Item = '\' order by ProductNum desc]
```

every single qoute is converted to "\" and double quotation is converted to " \" "

I also tried terminating it using ";" and injected it with this query

```
SELECT * FROM Shop
```

But it just returned the same error

```
 Error Query [SELECT * FROM Shop Where Item = 'SELECT * FROM Shop ' order by ProductNum desc]
```

Is there any possibility That I could Inject my own sql query?
PS I tried ";" alone and it didn't showed any error unlike " ' "

Comment: Asking for help with breaking the law.... Not a good idea!

Comment: I agree with @Jeroen-ITNerdbox: There are not many [results for `inurl:"/itemshop_secure.php"` on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=inurl:%22/itemshop_secure.php%22).

Comment: You guys are assuming that he's not testing the security of a plugin or his own website.

Comment: @wireghoul “I found this vulnerability within a website.”

Comment: Are you sure it’s actually MySQL and not [a DBMS that requires comparable data types like SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175118.aspx)? Otherwise I wouldn’t have any clue why the last query would fail.

Comment: @Gumbo I', not sure if its a MySQL i just assumed. 
This website Im hacking has a bounty system so technically its not illegal as long as I reported it.

Comment: So what website are you talking about?

Comment: http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/questions/897/clarify-our-stance-on-black-hat-questions/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the server has php configured with magic quotes on. Since the example query provided doesn't contain any quotes you won't need to inject any quotes. Something like `1 union select @@version from shop -- -` should give you an error about unions needing the same number of columns, proving the injection.